# Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined Q.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous, q

I am trying to populate Array asynchronously with data captured from MongoDB. I have a set of functions, which should execute one by one to merge 2 results from different tables into one, but upon execution, error is porduced:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

Here is a code of the router:

```
var Co2 = require("./../models/co2.model"),
  Dht = require("./../models/co2.model"),
  express = require("express"),
  q = require("q"),
  router = express.Router();

router.get("/all", function(req, res, next) {
  var co2Collector = function() {
    Co2.showAll(function(err, results) {
      co2Data = [];
      if (err) {
        res.json(err);
      }
      for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        co2Data.push(results[i]);
      }
      return co2Data;
    });
  };

  var dhtCollector = function() {
    Dht.showAll(function(err, results) {
      dhtData = [];
      if (err) {
        res.json(err);
      }
      for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        dhtData.push(results[i]);
      }
      return dhtData;
    });
  };

  var dataMerge = function(co2Data, dhtData) {
    mergedData = [];

    mergedData = mergedData.concat(co2Data, dhtData);
    res.json({
      message: "Done!",
      result: mergedData
    });
  };

  q
    .fcall(co2Collector())
    .then(dhtCollector())
    .then(dataMerge())
    .done();
});

module.exports = router;
```

The logic seems to be correct to me, but, then again, I am new to this kind of stuff and documentation is a little bit vague for my understanding.
Thanks for the help!

P.S: Can the issue be in the Schema and static method? In return, no matter what adjustments are made to the code, result is either `undefined`, either `null`.

Here is my mongoose schema:

```
var CO2Schema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
    location:{ type: String,required: true },
    reading: { type: String, required: true }
    },
    {
    timestamps: { createdAt : 'created_at', updatedAt : 'updated_at' },
    }
);

// Get CO2 results
CO2Schema.statics.showAll = function(cb) {
    return this.find({}, cb);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are calling all three functions upfront, and waiting on the responses

```
q
  .fcall(co2Collector())
  .then(dhtCollector())
  .then(dataMerge())
  .done();
```

is effectively:

```
var a = co2Collector();
var b = dhtCollector();
var c = dataMerge();

q
  .fcall(a)
  .then(b)
  .then(c)
  .done();
```

You should either pass in the function itself as the argument, or an arrow function.

```
q
  .fcall(co2Collector)
```

or

```
q
  .fcall(() => co2Collector())
```

etc.

Comment: OK, that resolves the logical issue. But now, instead of array as JSON response, I get `{ "message": "Done!", "result": [ null, null ]}`

Answer (score 0):

If this is a func returning promise then you need to return it.
`Co2.showAll` from `co2Collector` so that `q` can pass the value to the next chaining function.
Need to call `.all([co2Collector(), dhtCollector()])` so that both the values are passed to `dataMerge`

`q.fcall(dhtCollector)` is needed to convert the function to a promise

```
var Co2 = require("./../models/co2.model"),
  Dht = require("./../models/co2.model"),
  express = require("express"),
  q = require("q"),
  router = express.Router();

router.get("/all", function(req, res, next) {
  var co2Collector = function() {
    return Co2.showAll(function(err, results) {
      co2Data = [];
      if (err) {
        res.json(err);
      }
      for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        co2Data.push(results[i]);
      }
      return co2Data;
    });
  };

  var dhtCollector = function() {
    return Dht.showAll(function(err, results) {
      dhtData = [];
      if (err) {
        res.json(err);
      }
      for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        dhtData.push(results[i]);
      }
      return dhtData;
    });
  };

  var dataMerge = function(results) {
    co2Data = results[0].value;
    dhtData = results[1].value;
    mergedData = [];

    mergedData = mergedData.concat(co2Data, dhtData);
    res.json({
      message: "Done!",
      result: mergedData
    });
    return mergedData;
  };

  q
    .all([q.fcall(co2Collector), q.fcall(dhtCollector)])
    .then(dataMerge)
    .done();
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Seems like `co2Data = results[0].value;` is undefined. I don't get it, since when I `console.log()` it, it returns a JSON file.

Comment: I think this is what needed
`q.all([q.fcall(co2Collector), q.fcall(dhtCollector)])`

Comment: After hour of poking around, I still cant get it to work. When accessing API on that route, I get `{ "message": "Done!", "result": [ null, null ] }` and I have made some minor changes to code as well. `dhtCollector` is catching `co2Collector`'s result for no reason as well.